# Is the continuous map between CW-complexes a cofibration?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

If $f:A \rightarrow X$ is a continuous map between CW-complexes, then is $f$ necessarily a cofibration? I know that when $A$ is a subcomplex of $X$ and $f$ is the inclusion, the conclusion is true. Also, when $f$ is cellular, we can use the mapping cylinder to show the conclusion is true. But how about the general map $f$?

Answer (score 1):

A cofibration is a closed inclusion (injective with closed image) for Hausdorff spaces and so not all continuous maps between CW-complexes are cofibrations. Example $f\colon\{1,2\}\rightarrow\{1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Why an answer after so many years? Because there are some more aspects.

The minimal requirement for $f : A \to X$ to be a cofibration is that it is a closed embedding (all cofibrations are embeddings, and if $X$ is Hausdorff then $f(A)$ is closed in $X$).

Now have a look at [Is a closed embedding of CW-complexes a cofibration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3111988).

You will see that it true at least if $X$ is locally finite.